# Adding one or more instance of a class in another class

Tags: javascript, html, class, methods, attributes

I have `Movie` and `Actor` classes. I need to add an `addCast(cast)` method that allows the addition of one or more `Actors` to a movie.

I already have:

```
class Movie{
    constructor(name, year, duration){
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
class Actor{
    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**I should be able to do something like:**

> terminator.addCast(arnold);
>
> terminator.addCast(otherCast); //otherCast could be an array of `Actor`'s

How do I do this?

Should I need to add an `actors` attribute (in `Movie`) to add actors in it using `addCast(cast)`? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Post the code for the class you have? Generally you can do `terminator.addCast = function(...` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following could work (adapt to your needs):

```
class Movie{
    constructor(name, year, duration){
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.cast = []; // initialy we have an empty cast, to be added by addCast
    },
    addCast(cast){
       // in general it can accept an array of actors or a single actor
       if ( cast instanceof Actor) {
           cast = [cast]; // make it an array
       }
       for(var i=0; i<cast.length; i++) {
          this.cast.push(cast[i]);
       }
       return this; // make it chainable
    }
}
```

Then you can add cast to your movies like so:

```
terminator.addCast(new Actor('Arnold', 47)); // add single actor as cast
terminator.addCast([
  new Actor('An Actor', 30),
  new Actor('Another Actor', 40),
]); // add array of actors
```